# Is there a way to not trigger zapier zap when I update a contact via API in Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts-api, zapier, podio

I am updating Google Contacts by making an API call to Google Contacts API and I want to have sync between Google Contacts and a third party app like Podio.

So whenever I update a contact in google contacts it should sync up with Podio and vice versa.

And I have a zap set up in Zapier which triggers when a contact is updated in Google Contacts.

My question is will the zap trigger when I make an API call to update a contact in Google Contacts? if yes, then is there a way I can make it so it does not trigger my zap.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, unless u add a time-sensitive custom field and check for that in Zapier urself

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was hoping the answer could've been a hook event, like when you update a contact in Google Contacts via API, it doesn't consider that update as a hook event.

Comment: I also searched for any way we can consider that update a non hook event, but found nothing in terms of hook events in Google Contacts.